# What's the best way to make mass eth transfers programmatically?

Tags: parity

I am working on an issue where I need to make a mass transfer of ETH to different accounts. I do not wish to do it manually. What's the best way to make such transfers programmatically without human interference?

Comment: You may simply call the `sendTransacton` in a loop jsut as in simple javascript.

Answer (score 1):

Such functions as [`sendTransaction()`](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JavaScript-API#web3ethsendtransaction) accept only 0-1 argument as `to` (receiver).

There is no function which will send ETH to different accounts in one transaction.

---

If you need to send same amount of ETH to an array of accounts, you can do it like this:

```
// tx - transaction object
// accounts - array of addresses 
// value - price you are willing to send in Wei
function sendTransactionToAccounts(tx, accounts, value) {
   tx.value = value;
   for (let i = 0; i < accounts.length(); i++) {
      tx.to = accounts[i];
      web3.eth.sendTransaction(tx);
   }
}
```

***NOTE***: Code above is just an example